# get the representative elements from an array according to their position inside the array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, filter, underscore.js

This doubt is about underscore.js but can be resolved with normal javascript.

Assume we have one array

```
['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
```

According to one parameter, I want to show only X representative elements of the array.

For example.

- If I want 2 elements. For me the representive will be: ['Jan', 'Dec']
- For 3 elements: ['Jan', 'Jul', 'Dec']
- For 4 elements: ['Jan', 'Apr', 'Sep', 'Dec']
- and so...

Requeriments:

1. I always want first and last elements
2. The number of items will be 2 or more

Thanks

Comment: I'm not very sure if I understood your question, but are you looking to extract a subset of array items?

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the pattern of your examples, "representative" are the first, last and N-2 elements from the middle.

```
function representative(arr, n) {
    n = Math.max(n, Math.min(arr.length, 2));
    var offset = (arr.length - 1) / (n - 1);
    var out = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += offset) out.push(arr[0|Math.round(i)]);
    return out;
}

var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
console.log(representative(months, 2));
console.log(representative(months, 3));
console.log(representative(months, 4));
```

would seem to work, though the definition of "middle" is up to debate...

```
// output
[ 'Jan', 'Dec' ]
[ 'Jan', 'Jul', 'Dec' ]
[ 'Jan', 'May', 'Aug', 'Dec' ]
```

Comment: Perfect. The middle is up to debate but I don't it's a problem to round floor or ceil in this case. Thanks agains